# How do gravity anomalies on Earth comply with conservation of energy?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, earth, geophysics

Gravitational acceleration varies from place to place on Earth in a range of about 0.02 percent and is caused by density distributions within the Earth. Imagine an experiment where you move around the earth at a constant altitude and letting a mass fall at greater $g$ and pulling that mass up at smaller $g$; how does that comply with energy conservation?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem here is that $U = mgh$ is an approximation that we can make by assuming a constant value of $g$.  Even taking it a bit further and using

$$U = -G\frac{m_1m_2}{r}$$

will make some assumptions about the density and shape of earth if you consider one of the masses to be that of the whole earth.  In reality, you'd need to sum the contributions of the mass at every location on earth accounting for their various densities in order to calculate the potential energy at any given position using the above formula.  Therefore, at a constant altitude (if you can maintain it somehow), your potential energy will be varying slightly the whole way around.  If you were in orbit, your speed would change slightly as you pick up some of that energy change.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the strength of the Earth's gravity changes (slightly) from place to place. However, you can't just treat Earth's gravity as a varying number; it is a vector. It mostly points down towards the center of the Earth, but those same gravitational anomalies which cause the general strength of gravity to vary also cause it to deviate from what you'd generally call "vertical".

For instance, if you flying over a plain, and there's a mountain in your path, gravity will be stronger when you're over the mountain than when you're at some distance from the mountain. However, as you approach the mountain gravity will actually be (slightly) tilted and pulling you towards the mountain, and then as you fly away from the mountain the tilt will go the other way and pull back on you as you leave the mountain's vicinity. This is how the [GRACE satellites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_Recovery_and_Climate_Experiment) measure the Earth's gravitational anomalies, by measuring how each satellite slows down and speeds up.

So, what does this have to do with your proposed [counterexample to conservation of energy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2D9FcjTNaEk)? Well, as you travel over the earth, lowering and raising your mass, it would all work fine if gravity were always perpendicular to your flight path. But it isn't; it varies fore and aft as you approach and depart the anomalies. This means that the tension on the rope will pull you forward or back as well, which is just enough to cancel out any energy gain you may experience.

Comment: You say that the Earth's center of mass and the center of rotation of the flight are not equal, right? In that case gravity is not always perpendicluar to the flight path. But if those two points overlap (in a hypothetical thought experiment) gravity would always be perpendicluar to the flight path.

Comment: @Chris No: the local gravity vector does **not** always point to the Earth's center of mass.

Comment: I don't understand why the aft gravity vector as you depart the mountain slows you down more than the fore gravity vector as you approach the mountain speeds you up. It should cancel out imho.

Comment: It does cancel out, EXCEPT when you're moving actively that additional mass further into and out of the gravity well.